# Minimizing trace of inverse of a symmetric matrix with all components of the matrix related

Tags: matrices, optimization, inverse, trace

Let a symmetric matrix $A$ be:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b & -c\\ -b & d & -e\\ -c & -e & f\end{bmatrix}$$
All the values $a, b, \cdots , f \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and infact all the components are $\geq 1$. I have an optimization problem to minimize the trace of inverse of this matrix. Also, all the values in the matrix are somehow related (i.e increasing $a$ increases $b, c, \cdots f$). So there are two options,

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ Maximize $a$ which increases the value diagonal components but decreases the off diagonal components (or makes them more negative), or

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ Minimize $a$ which increases the off diagonal components (makes them less negative) but minimizes the diagonal components.

Is there a theorem of way to prove that either of the two cases is the option to go when looking to minimize trace($A^{-1}$)?

Comment: But how are they even related?

Comment: Lets just say increasing $a$ increases $b$ through $f$. So all the off diagonal components (with minus sign) are minimized. The off elements are not really a function of each other but increasing one element makes sure to increase another element.

Comment: How does it increase? Linearly?

Comment: Yes linearly. Specifically think of $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as the variable that I need to optimize. The components of the matrix are $$\begin{bmatrix} a_1^T X a_1 & - b_1^T X b_1 & - c_1^T X c_1 \\ -b_1^T X b_1 &  d_1^T X d_1 & - e_1^T X e_1  \\ -c_1^T X c_1 & - e_1^T X e_1 & f_1^T X f_1  \end{bmatrix}$$ where $a_1, b_1 \cdots f_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. So its like linear in all the parts with different cost.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Also it might be worth adding that the constraints are $$trace(X) = 1$$ and $$X \succeq0$$