# Is maximizing the trace of the inverse of a positive definite matrix with eigenvalues greater than $1$ the same as minimizing the determinant?

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Lets say I want to minimize the inverse of the following matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 &0 & 0\\ 0& \lambda_2 &0\\0& 0& \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix}$$ where all $\lambda \geq 1$. I also read that the determinant of the a the matrix $A$ can be given by:
$$\det(A) =  \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 $$. The trace of inverse of $A$ is given by:
$$trace(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_3}=\frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3 + \lambda_1 \lambda_3}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3}$$

So for $\lambda \geq 1$, is it safe to say that minimizing the trace of inverse of of A is the same as maximizing the determinant of A?

Comment: What about the other entries ? Is A a diagonal matrix ? Or are just the entries below the diagonal zeros ? Please be more precise!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Trace of inverse

Comment: Minimizing or maximizing subject to what constraints?  If your only constraint is $\lambda \ge 1$, then the determinant can be arbitrarily large, and the trace of $A^{-1}$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: @Peter It is a diagonal matrix. In general trace is always the sum of eigenvalues, no?

Comment: I think investigating matrix logarithm may be more fruitful. Then also starting from $I$ ($\lambda_k = 1 , \forall k$) becomes more natural (why?).

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant that and thats what I did above. My problem is a different one from this which I posted [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271241/minimizing-trace-of-inverse-of-a-symmetric-matrix-with-all-components-of-the-mat?noredirect=1).  I just want to see in which cases I can maximize the determinant and its equivalent to minimizing the trace of the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

This is not equivalent. Let $A_1 = diag(1,2,2)$ and $A_2 = diag(1,1,5)$. Then
$$
trace(A_1^{-1}) = 2 < trace(A_2^{-1}), \quad det(A_1) = 4 < det(A_2) \, . 
$$